# Dynamically change ASP.Net WebForms Control IDs While Maintaining State

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We're working with a third party system and we need to modify some ASP.Net controls so that they have a specific token added to their HTML id attribute (so the third party system can identify them from the request), as well as HTML comments before and after the controls' output.

Basically, we need to be able to take say a TextBox (say for "Employee First Name") and dynamically change its output to something like this:

```
<!-- FIZZBOT_START -->
<input id="EmployeeFirstName_FIZZBOT_" ... />
<!-- FIZZBOT_END -->
```

We would ideally like to implement this so that the developers only have to do something like this:

```
<xxx:FizzbotWrapper ID="MyWrapper" runat="server">
  <asp:TextBox ID="EmployeeFirstName" runat="server" />
</xxx:FizzbotWrapper>
```

**Is there any way to get such an interface to produce such output, while still being able to:**

- maintain control state across requests
- work properly with Validators
- work properly with UpdatePanels
- allow developers to refer to the original ID in the codebehind for readability (instead of having to refer to "EmployeeFirstName_FIZZBOT_"
- work with out-of-the box ASP.Net controls like TextBox and not just controls we've derived.

I've tried a few ways of doing this (the technique that was the most promising was [this](http://nunogomes.net/post/2008/06/02/ASPNET-Controls-Improving-automatic-ID-generation-Architectural-Changes-%28-Part-3%29.aspx), but I ran into some trouble getting it to work with validators, and it wouldn't work at all with controls we don't have the source code to).

Comment: Are you working with ASP.NET 4 or later? If so, then [Cleaner HTML Markup with ASP.NET 4 Web Forms - Client IDs](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx).

Comment: You can't expect the ID property to behave differently trying to keep one value in the server side and another on the client side. It is indeed the control's ID. I would suggest to think for something more feasible like building property "Wrappers" for your old controls to reduce the amount of generated code.